# Why is transform-origin: bottom not working?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to get a line appear "under" an input box when in focus. For some reason transform-origin "left" (that is if I change it to "right" it will appear from the right side, but with "left" it appears from the left) works but 'bottom' doesn't and it keeps appearing on top.

```css
.wrap-input{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
    height: 49px;
  }
  .inputForm {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #555555;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
  }

  .wrap-input::before{
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(128,0,0,1) 15%, rgba(238,174,150,1) 49%, rgba(128,0,0,1) 85%);
    display: block;
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
    transform-origin: left bottom;/*this line is problem*/
  }
  .wrap-input:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1, 1)
  }
```

```html
 <div class="wrap-input" data-validate="Valid email is: info@johndoe.com">
    <input class="inputForm" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">               
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that transform-origin isn't what you require - it tells the system the point from which any tranformation is to take place - it's relative to the element it's in, not to any 'owner'/parent/ancestor.

To position the pseudo element under the input element this snippet gives it position absolute and position left 0 and bottom 0 - these are relative to the actual div itself.

```css
.wrap-input {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
  height: 49px;
}

.inputForm {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #555555;
  line-height: 1.2;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.wrap-input::before {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(128, 0, 0, 1) 15%, rgba(238, 174, 150, 1) 49%, rgba(128, 0, 0, 1) 85%);
  display: block;
  transform: scale(0, 1);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
  transform-origin: left center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap-input:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1, 1)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-input" data-validate="Valid email is: info@johndoe.com">
  <input class="inputForm" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

Comment: your answer works. but it doesn't explain why left and right worked in my question code but bottom not..

Comment: I didn't see a right in  your question code. The bottom you used was on the transform-origin which was not what you meant - it moves the point about which transforms take place, it doesn't position the element. I tried to explain that in my answer - let me know if that's not enough explanation. The left position worked OK. The left in the transform-origin also was relative to the item being transformed, not to its 'owning' element and it 'worked' in the sense it was obeyed (as was the bottom).

Comment: I edited my question, and I now get what your saying. Thanx!!